# use taosBenchmark to insert binary data with specified length in command line

Tags: tdengine

In TDengine database, I tried to use taosBenchmark to write binary data with specified length in command line, but I got following error

```
root@Alex ~ $ taosBenchmark -b int,int,binary(100)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

what is the correct way to use taosBenchamark to write binary data in command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `taosBenchmark -b int,intbinary\(100\)`